# Google search of links:mysite.com returns less links than imagined

Tags: google, backlinks

I did a Google search `links: example.com` and it only returns 3 results.  I know there are a lot my more back links in existence than that. Why does Google not show the other links I have to my site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google disabled this search command a few years back because far to many people were find to be reserve engineering other peoples links. Additionally it only contained a sample and not the full links any how. You can find some other [search commands that may be useful](http://moz.com/blog/25-killer-combos-for-googles-site-operator) but ultimately there is no effective way of searching links using Google search.

Google's Webmaster Tools contains a site backlinks however it is often incomplete or generally slow. Your best bet if this is important to you is too use other methods that crawl sites and adds it to their database, for example [SEO Majestic](http://www.majesticseo.com/), [SEO Profiler](http://www.seoprofiler.com/) and many more....

Answer (score 0):

For the best answer try to submit your website to [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en). You will get there all the links that Google take in count.